# Problem on charset print in Python and tkinter on Eclipse + PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I need to use and print some text in different languages using Python and Tkinter.
I am using Python 3.8.6 on Windows and Eclipse with PyDev plugin.
In the following example I try to print a couple of strings in English and Italian but when I try to run/debug it does not start and produces this specific error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 384: invalid continuation byte
Any help will be appreciated.

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# \file testutf8.py
# \brief
#
# \version rel. 1.0
# \date Created on 2022-03-25
# \author massimo
# Copyright (C) 2022 Massimo Manca - AIoTech
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# encoding: utf-8

sa = "Penalty: "
sb = "Penalità: "
penalty = 10
strPenalty = sa + str(penalty)

print( strPenalty )
```

Comment: That sounds like the file is encoded as ISO-8859-1 or something like that - not UTF-8. 0xe0 is à in the ISO-8859-1 encoding, and is not valid on its own in UTF-8

Comment: Yes, sure the PC is running Windows Italian version so cp1252 and the IDE is Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

As long as the encoding used for the console (in Eclipse) and the `PYTHONIOENCODING` match, things should good (as far as you print `str` on `Python 3`).

I particularly try to make sure everything is `utf-8`, so, make sure that the `Text file encoding` is marked as such inside of Eclipse:

[image: Text file encoding]

Usually that should be enough as other settings are usually derived from there, but you can also double-check your launch configuration:

[image: Launch encoding]

Comment: the Eclipse Workspace setup is Cp1252 so it should recognize without any problem the 0xe0 character. The problem seems related to Eclipse because the same code works on Idle.

Comment: Well, you explicitly have `# encoding: utf-8` in that file. If it should be `cp1252` then you should specify that properly in the file... i.e.: you need to have the encoding declaration in the first or second line in your file (see: https://peps.python.org/pep-0263/ how to do it properly).

Comment: I already tryed with cp1252 instead of utf-8 but it did not work. Eclipse source files are encode in cp1252. At the moment I foud a solution for ini/cfg files and to print strings in cp1252 but none solution to use cp1252 encoded strings in tkinter